# AngularJS - How to store JWT token in $localStorage

Tags: angularjs, jwt, token, access-token, express-jwt

I have this service call apiService, in there i can get the token that is generated in the server side.

```
angular.module('miniMynd')
    .service('apiService', function ($http) {
       return {
         loginUser: function(user){
           $http.post("http://localhost:3010/api/login", user).then(function(response){
             console.log(response.data) * I get the token* 
           })
         },
       }
    });
```

my loginCtrl

```
$scope.login = function(){
  $apiService.loginUser($scope.credentials); * I pass the crendentials to my function on the client side and i receive a token in the service above*
}
```

I have try to put the token in my $localStorage but im getting a inject error because only providers are injectable in configuration blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont require to define any module or inject any other module in the application.
inject $window in your application and then you can access the localstorage module like this

```
angular.module('miniMynd', [])
     .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $apiService.loginUser($scope.credentials);
}]);
```

and then,

```
angular.module('miniMynd')
    .service('apiService', function ($http,$window) {
       return {
         loginUser: function(user){
           $http.post("http://localhost:3010/api/login", user).then(function(response){
              $window.localStorage.setItem('token', response.data);
           })
         },
       }
    });
```

and you can retrieve the localStorage value like this

```
$window.localStorage.getItem('token');
```

Comment: Sajeetharan !! Thank you sir !!

Comment: is it safe to store token as plan text ?